# How can I insert html elements written in the pug syntax using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to insert an HTML element in my pug file.
The problem is that when I try to insert an element in the pug file like this:

```
      $('.section-reviews').html('h1 Johann Sebastian Bach');
```

Or to insert a mixin:

```
      $('.section-reviews').html('+reviewPublish()');
```

I doesn´t work. It inserts the element as a text, and not as a HTML element
How could I fix this problem?

Comment: jQuery isn't going to process your Pug syntax. You have to ensure that you've got Pug on the client and then explicitly call it to expand the templates.

Comment: `I want to insert an HTML element in my pug file` Why? What's the context? You don't send Pug files to browsers, as they don't understand it. You must convert it to HTML first. Pug is a preprocessor language, it has nothing to do with the DOM in your browser, you can't manipulate it with jQuery. We need a bigger picture of what's going on here

Comment: Actually I would like to insert a new mixin in my pug file when the user hits a button.                           
$('.section-reviews').html('+reviewPublish()');

Comment: That´s the thing. How could I do that?

Comment: Anyway thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/PythonLinks/pug/blob/master/README.md#installation-on-the-client

"If you want to compile Pug templates in the browser you need to include Pug for the browser. Here is the latest version of [Pug for the browser in standalone form](https://pugjs.org/js/pug.js). It only supports the very latest browsers, though, and is a large file, and compilation is comparitively slow, so it is recommended that only the developers do this, and then save and serve the generated javascript."

```js
const pug = require('pug');
$(function() {
  $('#content').html(pug.compile(`
mixin pet(name)
  li.pet= name
ul
  +pet('cat')
  +pet('dog')
  +pet('pig')
`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://pugjs.org/js/pug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use mixin that are already defined in the pug file?

Comment: You would probably need to include the mixin definition inside pug.compile()